# Cannot install Guppy into my project

Tags: python, pip, guppy

I'm currently facing a weird issue that I cannot successfully install `guppy` package into my project using the command:

`pip install guppy`

The console ends up with:

> clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c src/sets/sets.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6/src/sets/sets.o
>   src/sets/sets.c:77:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
>   INITFUNC (void)
>        ^
>   src/sets/sets.c:39:18: note: expanded from macro 'INITFUNC'
>   #define INITFUNC initsetsc
>                      ^
>   1 error generated.
>   error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
>
> Command "/Users/unifiedloaner/.virtualenvs/communique/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/kb/ynmw5jys2_ddb7_1qy8x6l7r0000gr/T/pip-install-r90baffb/guppy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/kb/ynmw5jys2_ddb7_1qy8x6l7r0000gr/T/pip-record-mbb2utye/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/unifiedloaner/.virtualenvs/communique/bin/../include/site/python3.6/guppy" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/kb/ynmw5jys2_ddb7_1qy8x6l7r0000gr/T/pip-install-r90baffb/guppy/

I'm using pip 10.0.0 and Python 3.6 in my virtualenv `communique`

Comment: The guppy doesn't support python3.x. See the full answer and alterantive in the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks, do we have any tool supporting python3.x to show the memory usage?

Comment: [link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/python/profiling-memory-usage-in-python)
Maybe this will help.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm using Python 3.x, that's why the tool doesn't work.